# Find match between two sets of data in javascript with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have two list of data and I would like to compare each element of `listA` to value of `listB` using [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

Example:

```
var listA = ["Y", "A", "Z", "T"];
```

```
var listB = [{id:15467, value:"E"}, {id:23453, value:"A"}, {id:76564, value:"O"}, {id:86543, value:"T"}];
```

Take one element at a time on `listA` and find matching value of `listB`.
If true, return the object of `listB`.

```
result = [{id:23453, value:"A"}, {id:86543, value:"T"}]
```

Hope you can help me?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is: _.each(ListA, function (listAElement) {
                        _.filter(ListB, function (listBElement) {
                            if (listAElement === listBElement.Value) {
                                return result.push(listBElement);
                            }
                        });
                    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter) with [`_.includes`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#includes).

```js
var listA = ["Y", "A", "Z", "T"],
    listB = [{ id: 15467, value: "E" }, { id: 23453, value: "A" }, { id: 76564, value: "O" }, { id: 86543, value: "T" }],
    result = _.filter(listB, ({ value }) => _.includes(listA, value));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like the destructuring there of `value`. I always forget about that technique!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Filter all itens

```js
let listA = ["Y", "A", "Z", "T"];
let listB = [{id:15467, value:"E"}, {id:23453, value:"A"}, {id:76564, value:"O"}, {id:86543, value:"T"}];
let result = [];

listA.map(letter =>{
  for (var i = 0; i < listB.length; i++) {
    if(letter == listB[i].value){
      result.push(listB[i])
    }
  }
})


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can can make use of the `filter` and `includes` operators:

- "Filter" `listB` items
- ... using a predicate function
- ... which checks if `listA` includes `value`

```
_.filter(listB, function(listBItem) { 
    return _.includes(listA, listBItem.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use lodash's `_.intersectionWith()` to find the common denominator between two arrays, the items and the order would be that of `listB`:

```js
const listA = ["Y", "A", "Z", "T"];
const listB = [{ id: 86543, value: "T" }, { id: 15467, value: "E" }, { id: 23453, value: "A" }, { id: 76564, value: "O" }]; // I've moved value: "T" to the start

const result = _.intersectionWith(
  listB, 
  listA,
  (a, b) => a.value === b
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

To get items in `listB` ordered by `listA`, use lodash's `_.flow()` to create a function. Convert `listB` to an object (with `_.keyBy()`) setting the `value` as the keys. Extract the items ordered by `listA` with `_.at()`, and then `_.reject` all undefined items:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, keyBy, at, reject, isUndefined } = _;

const fn = paths => flow(
  pr(keyBy, 'value'), // convert listB to an object, with the value as the key
  pr(at, paths), // get the items from the object ordered by listA
  pr(reject, isUndefined) // remove undefined items
);

const listA = ["Y", "A", "Z", "T"];
const listB = [{ id: 86543, value: "T" }, { id: 15467, value: "E" }, { id: 23453, value: "A" }, { id: 76564, value: "O" }];

const result = fn(listA)(listB);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```